# Difference between android.enableD8.desugaring in Android Studio 3.1 and android.enableD8

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dex, android-studio-3.1

In Android Studio 3.0 there is an option `android.enableD8` to enable D8 (Next-generation Dex Compiler).
In Android Studio 3.1 a new option was added for this like `android.enableD8.desugaring` as per their updates.

What actually does `android.enableD8.desugaring` do in Android Studio 3.1 and what's the difference compared to the `android.enableD8` option?

Answer (score 13):

The `desugar` step is executed normally after `javac` to optimize the bytecode. Enabling desugaring in D8 will remove that step entirely, and execute `desugar` as part of D8, making it faster and more optimized.

Source:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/next-generation-dex-compiler-now-in.html